# What are "pairs" when comparing the records of each record pair in recordlinkage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates, data-cleaning, record-linkage

I have a [set of real estate ad data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XUjqeXVgjZJ8jVNAn9MeIb9zHLhVj4mwRs-hk1P050o/edit?usp=sharing). Several of the lines are about the same real estate, so it's full of duplicates that aren't exactly the same. It looks like this :

```
    ID  URL CRAWL_SOURCE    PROPERTY_TYPE   NEW_BUILD   DESCRIPTION IMAGES  SURFACE LAND_SURFACE    BALCONY_SURFACE ... DEALER_NAME DEALER_TYPE CITY_ID CITY    ZIP_CODE    DEPT_CODE   PUBLICATION_START_DATE  PUBLICATION_END_DATE    LAST_CRAWL_DATE LAST_PRICE_DECREASE_DATE
0   22c05930-0eb5-11e7-b53d-bbead8ba43fe    http://www.avendrealouer.fr/location/levallois...   A_VENDRE_A_LOUER    APARTMENT   False   Au rez de chaussÃ©e d'un bel immeuble rÃ©cent,...   ["https://cf-medias.avendrealouer.fr/image/_87...   72.0    NaN NaN ... Lamirand Et Associes    AGENCY  54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2017-03-22T04:07:56.095 NaN 2017-04-21T18:52:35.733 NaN
1   8d092fa0-bb99-11e8-a7c9-852783b5a69d    https://www.bienici.com/annonce/ag440414-16547...   BIEN_ICI    APARTMENT   False   Je vous propose un appartement dans la rue Col...   ["http://photos.ubiflow.net/440414/165474561/p...   48.0    NaN NaN ... Proprietes Privees  MANDATARY   54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2018-09-18T11:04:44.461 NaN 2019-06-06T10:08:10.89  2018-09-25
...
```

I want to find records in the dataset belonging to the same entity with recordlinkage. So I read [the docs](https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref-compare.html) and mimitized the same :

```
indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
indexer.full()
candidate_links = indexer.index(df)

print (len(df), len(candidate_links))
```

2164 2340366

Each record pair being a candidate match, to classify the candidate record pairs into matches and non-matches, I want to compare the records on all attributes both records have in common. The recordlinkage module has a class named Compare. This class is used to compare the records. The following code shows how I compared attributes :

compare_cl = recordlinkage.Compare()

```
compare_cl = recordlinkage.Compare()

compare_cl.exact('SURFACE', 'SURFACE', label='SURFACE')

features = compare_cl.compute(pairs, df)
```

However it gives me back :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-1e55ea540dbd> in <module>
      9 #compare_cl.string('address_1', 'address_1', threshold=0.85, label='address_1')
     10 
---> 11 features = compare_cl.compute(pairs, df)

NameError: name 'pairs' is not defined
```

And I can't find what pairs are in [the docs](https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref-compare.html) ...

Answer (score 0):

try with candidate_links

https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref-compare.html

compute(pairs, x, x_link=None)
Compare the records of each record pair.

Calling this method starts the comparing of records.

Parameters: 
pairs (pandas.MultiIndex) – A pandas MultiIndex with the record pairs to compare. The indices in the MultiIndex are indices of the DataFrame(s) to link.